# How can I add admin members to kaizala group with the rest api?

Tags: rest, kaizala

So, the default is that my logged user from the access token is whom has admin permissions but I don't know how to make any member an admin.

This is the body that I'm using from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/kaizala.microsoft.com/group%20management%20apis/creategroup).

```
{
  "name": "Test Group",
  "welcomeMessage": "Welcome to group created programmatically",
  "members": [
    "{{mobile-number-3}}"
  ],
  "memberUserIds": [
    "{{loggedin-user-id}}"
  ],
  "groupType": "Group",
  "GroupPhoto": "",
  "BackgroundPhoto": "",
  "ShortDescriptionString": "Short description",
  "LongDescriptionString": "Long description"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though there is no documentation of it, a simple `PUT` on endpoint `https://{endpoint-url}/v1/groups/{group-id}/{member-id}` with a JSON payload of `{ "role": "Admin" }` works for me

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following API with JSON payload of `{ "role": "Admin" }`.

```
{​​​​​​​{​​​​​​​endpoint-url}​​​​​​​}​​​​​​​/v1/groups/{​​​​​​​{​​​​​​​group-id}​​​​​​​}​​​​​​​/members/{{member-id}}
```

The **"members"** keyword is important here and it worked for me like this. Also, you can grant admin permissions only for group members. Otherwise, you will get an error from API.